# resizing shapes to window size

Tags: c#, wpf

I have been trying to figure out a hopefully pretty simple thing for days now, but I just don't get it. What I want to have is a window with, let's says a button and a Polygon in **two different containers**.

When resizing the window I want the button to keep its size and relative position (eg. to the upper left corner, without being covered by the other container) and to resize the Polygon (it should not keep its width/height ratio) without changing its stroke-thickness.

It is very **IMPORTANT** that I can create the Polygon completely from the code-behind, defining it in xaml **doesn't** help at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may create a Path with a scaled [PathGeometry](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.pathgeometry.aspx) that uses the width and height of its container as scaling factors. Thus you could specify the geometry entirely in logical coordinates, ranging from 0 to 1 in either direction:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Button HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="5" Content="Button"/>
    <Canvas x:Name="polylineCanvas" Grid.Row="1">
        <Path Stroke="Blue" StrokeThickness="3">
            <Path.Data>
                <PathGeometry x:Name="polyline">
                    <PathGeometry.Transform>
                        <ScaleTransform
                            ScaleX="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=polylineCanvas}"
                            ScaleY="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=polylineCanvas}"/>
                    </PathGeometry.Transform>
                </PathGeometry>
            </Path.Data>
        </Path>
    </Canvas>
</Grid>
```

Now you may specify the geometry in code like shown below:

```
var points = new Point[]
{
    new Point(0.1, 0.1),
    new Point(0.9, 0.1),
    new Point(0.9, 0.9),
    new Point(0.1, 0.9)
};

var figure = new PathFigure
{
    StartPoint = points[0],
    IsClosed = true
};

var segment = new PolyLineSegment(points.Skip(1), true);
figure.Segments.Add(segment);
polyline.Figures.Add(figure);
```

You may alternatively use a [StreamGeometry](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.streamgeometry.aspx) instead of a PathGeometry.

Comment: Thank you very much! I managed to do the binding in the code  behind, learned a lot and finally got my pattern to move on.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have anchors in WPF. There are many layout controls and each one has a different way to set the position of a control.

For example, controls positioned in Grids use the margins and their size to be positioned. Controls in Canvas use the `Canvas.Top`, `Canvas.Left`, `Canvas.Right` and `Canvas.Bottom` to position. Controls in `StackPanels` use the margins to get a separation.

I recommend that you take a look at these articles about layout in WPF get what do you want:

> http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/WPFLayoutQS.aspx
>
> http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/dpatra/105202009083754AM/1.aspx

Hope this helps!